# How to remove countertops in Fallout 4?

Tags: fallout-4

I took over the Covenant and turned it into a settlement. I wanted to renovate the store, and build it as a bar or a room for settlers. I tried clicking the countertop and tried the commands `disable` and `markfordelete`. Sometimes I can click on it, but it looks like I'm clicking through the countertop since the object behind it is the one that gets removed. And sometimes I get the error `Picked Non Ref AV Object: ""`.

Is there any way to remove it?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay I found another way. I used **Creation Kit** program.

I checked the basics on how to use it, loaded the Covenant map, removed the countertop and save it as a mod file. Loaded it in the game and now the countertop is removed as I wanted.

Answer (score 3):

The `disable` and `markfordelete` commands don't work for these 'non-referenced AV objects', as they are predefined combinations of separate models, often referred to as combined objects or precombines.

- **You can reposition them using the `ModPos <axis> <distance in units>` command**.
  Doing this along the z-axis is usually the best option, so the command would be `setPos z -40`, for example.
  There is also a `setPos` command, but you'll need absolute positions for this (the <distance in units> is <position in coordinates>), and you'll probably need to find the current position using `getPos`. Note that for the z-position of an object `setPos` can work equally fine, as most of the Fallout 4 terrain is likely far above z-position 0 anyway.
- Alternatively, **you can disable the `bUseCombinedObjects`** by switching its value to `0` in the *Fallout4Custom.ini* file (default location: *C:\Users\<username>\Documents\My games\Fallout4*).
  This *will* increase render time, especially in heavily cluttered areas, as the predefined models are treated as separate parts once again (but, in case you're planning on using a texture replacer, you might have to change this value anyway).

  [Here](https://bethesda.net/community/post/581002) is a wonderfully in-depth post by user AndrewCX about the AV objects, why there used, and why you shouldn't want to start messing with them.
- **And then, as always, there are mods**.
  Like [this one](https://www.nexusmods.com/fallout4/mods/4640/?), called Spring Cleaning.

Comment: Great! using the command, I'm wondering how do I select the object that I want to reposition if I cant select it?